# How to access further properties of a table using nav properties of EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I have student and grade table, with one to many relationship

```
Student
======
stud_id (pk)
stud_name
grade_id(fk)

Grade
=====
grade_id
grade_name
```

My model/entity classes are as follows

```
Student
======
public int stud_id {get; set;}
public string stud_name {get; set;}
public int grade_id(fk) {get; set;}
public Grade grade {get; set;}

Grade
=====
public int grade_id {get; set;}
public string grade_name {get; set;}
public ICollection<Student> students {get; set;}
```

I have a DOT class to work in with LINQ queries

```
StudentDomain
============
public int stud_id {get; set;}
public string stud_name {get; set;}
public int grade_id(fk) {get; set;}
public Grade grade {get; set;}
```

in my DataAccessRepository class, I have a method

```
public IEnumerable<StudentDomain> GetStudent(int stud_id)
{
var result=  from st in db.Student
         join gr in db.Grade on st.grade_id==gr.grade_id
        select new StudentDomain
           {
              stud_id= st.stud_id,
              stud_name= st.stud_name,
               grade_id= gr.grade_id
                //here I want to add grade name just to display for the 
user but not to store in the database table
           }
return result.ToList();

}
```

I want to display the equivalent grade name of the grade Id in my browser, but I don't want it to be stored inside the database table. How do I get an access to grade name?

Comment: First of all: When you join you must use `equals` instead of `==`. Second: Why would it be stored if you just select it?

Comment: thanks for the advice to use `equals`  instead of `==` but I don't get you why would it be stored if selected, I don't want to store it in my database, I just want to display the name of the grade instead of grade id

Comment: I'm just saying: It will NOT be stored in your database. Where did you get that idea?

Answer (score 1):

i think you have a misunderstanding over linq query,you are not supposed to store any thing by linq query,just put gradename property inside your StudentDomain class as below

```
StudentDomain
============
public int stud_id {get; set;}
public string stud_name {get; set;}
public int grade_id(fk) {get; set;}
public int grade_name {get; set;}
```

and fill it like this

```
public IEnumerable<StudentDomain> GetStudent(int stud_id)
{
var result=  from st in db.Student
         join gr in db.Grade on st.grade_id==gr.grade_id
        select new StudentDomain
           {
              stud_id= st.stud_id,
              stud_name= st.stud_name,
               grade_id= gr.grade_id
               grade_name=gr.grade_name
           }
return result.ToList();

}
```

Comment: If I do so, I am getting all I need. I didn't know that I can repeat grade_name property in other model classes while it is already mentioned in its own model class which is Grade and navigation property is already set.